# Heroku login not working on Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, heroku, osx-elcapitan, heroku-toolbelt

When am trying to login to heroku from terminal, am getting the below error and login fails. Please help.

OS: Mac OS X El Capitan

Heroku:
`heroku version
heroku-toolbelt/3.43.2 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
heroku-cli/5.2.18-f850f09 (darwin-amd64) go1.6.2
You have no installed plugins.`

`heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: xxxxxx@xxxx.com
Password (typing will be hidden): 
 ▸    Post https://api.heroku.com/login: dial tcp: lookup api.heroku.com on 8.8.4.4:53: cannot unmarshal DNS message`

PS: I have tried `sudo heroku login` as well. But same result.

Comment: your dns isn't working, and can't get api.heroku.com->ip resolved.

Comment: What should I do? Am using Google DNS. Tried even with the default DNS, still getting same error.

Comment: `nslookup api.heroku.com`, if that fails, then figure out why dns is broken. and then that's not really a programming questions anymore, that's system maintenance/configuration, which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: This is the result

```nslookup api.heroku.com
Server:  8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
api.heroku.com canonical name = midgard.heroku.com.
midgard.heroku.com canonical name = midgard.herokussl.com.
midgard.herokussl.com canonical name = elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
Name: elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 54.243.105.250
Name: elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 23.21.149.112
Name: elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 54.225.188.133
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem was caused by DNS setting on your network.
Please remove the 8.8.8.8 from your DNS and it works for me.

Comment: What should I replace 8.8.8.8 with ?

Comment: I leave it blank, so it will use default DNS from your internet provider I guess.

Comment: With out Google Public DNS it will take my default ISP DNS which is still not working.

Comment: What do you get when run nslookup api.heroku.com after update your DNS?